# Going from JSON to generated CoffeeScript

Tags: javascript, json, coffeescript

I have currently hard-coded in some data for a demo of a project.  The code looks like this:

```
update: () =>
    t = getTime()
    if t == undefined
        zone = -1
    else if between(t, 100, 110) 
        zone = 1
    else if between(t, 111, 120) 
        zone = 2
```

Now, the next step is to take a json array of the form:

```
[{"start": 100, "end": 110, "zone": 1}, {"start": 111, "end": 120,"zone": 2}]
```

to make the generated code above.  Is this possible?  What is the best way to go about doing this?

Comment: I don't understand the question. Do you want to do what the `update` method does but with dynamic values that come from a JSON string, or to _generate_ the CoffeeScript code above from that JSON?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
fs = require 'fs'

json = fs.readFileSync 'PUT_FILENAME_HERE', 'utf-8'
data = JSON.parse json

for zoneData in data
  if between(t, zoneData.start, zoneData.end)
    zone = zoneData.zone
    break
```